# React error - ./src/App.js Line 16: Parsing error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

i tried a tutorial from their site and i encountered this error and i dont know what is wrong.
This is the code:

```
function formatName(user) {
        return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName; //this is line 16
      }

      const user = {
        firstName: 'Ciofliceanu';
        lastName: 'Serban';
      };

      const element = <h1>Hello, {formatName(user)}</h1>;

      ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I expect the output to be Hello, Ciofliceanu Serban but the output is: ./src/App.js
  Line 16:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

Comment: Have you tried replacing the semicolons in the definition of `user` with commas?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic you added this comment seconds before I posted my answer. If you want to post an answer, I can take my down.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Don't worry, thanks for being considerate. Sometimes SO can be rough :D

Comment: Really you should just flag it as a typo.

Comment: I replaced semicolons with comas and still same error...other ideas ?

Comment: @SC Can you please post the entirety of your `App.js` file? I do have an assumption what you might have wrong as well.

Answer (score 2):

The error is most likely really happening at definition of `user` as this is not a proper object literal:

```
const user = {
  firstName: 'Ciofliceanu';
  lastName: 'Serban';
};
```

Try replacing the `;` with `,`:

```
const user = {
  firstName: 'Ciofliceanu',
  lastName: 'Serban'
};
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Hello, i modified like you said and it still shows the same error...any idea ?

Comment: You need to provide more information regarding the configuration of your application. It’s not clear how/where you are compiling/running this. Did you use Create React App?